# React Redux Reselect - Undefined State

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, reselect

I have the following code in my react/redux app:

```
import { createSelector } from 'reselect';

const selectMembers = state => state.membersData;

const makeSelectLessonSets = createSelector(
  selectMembers,
  substate => substate.get('myData').toJS()
);
```

The problem is that sometimes `myData` is not yet defined, so `substate.get('myData')` will not get anything. And since I try to call `toJS()` on it, it shows the error: `undefined is not an object`.

But I don't know how to check if `substate.get('myData')` has returned a valid object inside `createSelector` before I call `toJS()` on it.

Can you please help with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added `?` before the dot this will not throw an error

```
import { createSelector } from 'reselect';

const selectMembers = state => state.membersData;

const makeSelectLessonSets = createSelector(
  selectMembers,
  substate => substate?.get('myData')?.toJS()
);
```

Comment: It's called [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)